# Polymorphic has_many in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have been reading up on [polymorphic associations in Ecto](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/389#issuecomment-75306708) quite a bit, and I agree with the opinion that having a native database reference between your tables is advantageous.

However, most of the times the polymorphic `belongs_to` is referenced, not the other way around (`has_many`). I'm still unsure how to deal with it properly.

In my case it's about a Phoenix backend API, I have a `Page` model, that has a number of `Widgets`. Each of this widgets has it's own table and model, since it needs to store and return different fields. Let's say we have a `TwoColumnWidget` and a `ThreeColumnWidget`, that both have a reference `page_id` to the `Page` model.

How would I model this ideally, right now I have an intermediate `Widget` model (with database), that has a column for to every possible widget type and picks the one where an id is present in one of the columns. This feels pretty hacky to me as I have to store an additional row in the database for every widget that needs to be synced, as well as the hassle to get the correct serializer/view for each concrete widget.

Since my domain has a lot of these types of relations, I want to find a better solution in general to ease further development. Any pointers?

Comment: When you say "with its own database", do you really me a complete database, or "its own table"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this assuming that you mean each widget type has its own table (schema). Since you appear to have a one-to-many relationship and not many-to-many between widgets and pages, you may want to consider a simple array of maps approach, presuming your using a db that supports it like postgress.

You need to be aware that maps are persisted in the database with string keys, not atom keys. So, if us save a struct to the db, when you read it back, it will be a map with string keys. So you would need to cast it back into a map like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Utils do

  def cast(%{} = schema, params) do
    struct schema, map_to_atom_keys(params)
  end
  def cast(module, params) when is_atom(module), do: cast(module.__struct__, params)

  def map_to_atom_keys(%{} = params) do
    Enum.reduce(params, %{}, fn({k, v}, acc) ->
      Map.put(acc, to_atom(k), v)
    end)
  end

  defp to_atom(key) when is_atom(key), do: key
  defp to_atom(key) when is_binary(key), do: String.to_existing_atom(key)

  def item_type(%{} = item), do: item_type(item.__struct__)
  def item_type(item) do
    Module.split(item)
    |> Enum.reverse
    |> hd
    |> to_string
  end
end
```

You could do something similar with a widgets table, where the variable data is stored as a map. if you store the struct name, then you could cast it back into the struct.

```
defmodule Widget do
  schema "widgets" do
    field :embedded_type, :string
    belongs_to :page, Page
    field :widget, :map
  end

  def changeset(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:embedded_type, :page_id, :widget])
    |> handle_widget(params)
  end
  defp handle_widget(changeset, %{widget: widget}) do
    changeset
    |> put_change(:embedded_type, widget.__struct__ |> inspect)
  end
end
```

And then you could use the above code to cast it back.

You can also be able to create each widget type with an embedded_schema and use Ecto to do the casting for you.